# Abrir página do facebook Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic, apache-cordova

Olá! Uso este código para abrir o aplicativo do Facebook diretamente na página no dispositivo.

```
<a href="#" class="link-fb" 
    onclick="window.open('fb://page/0000000000000', '_system'); return false;">
</a>
```

No `Android` funciona perfeitamente, abrindo na página enviada no parâmetro. Porém no `iOS` ele apenas abre o app do facebook na página inicial.

Alguém sabe o que está acontecendo? alguma sugestão?  Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiz assim em minha aplicação e deu certo no IOS E no Android

```
    <ion-list>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/GuiaCorretorPlus/"><ion-item>
      <ion-thumbnail item-start>
        <img src="assets/img/facebook_logo.png">
      </ion-thumbnail>
      <h2>Facebook</h2>
      <p>GuiaCorretor</p>
      <button ion-button clear item-end>View</button>
    </ion-item></a>
  </ion-list>
```

Comment: Obrigado por responder, testei dessa forma, mas ele abre o navegador.  Eu gostaria que abrisse o aplicativo do Facebook no dispositivo

Comment: Mas ai você teria que usar uma API para isto talvez.

Comment: Com o código que postei, está funcionando no Android,   já no ios ele abre o aplicativo mas não na página correta

Comment: Da uma olhada na documentação do cordova, talvez isto te ajude: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.6.0/cordova/inappbrowser/window.open.html